# IE7 not returning value of drop down

Tags: javascript, datetime, cross-browser, internet-explorer-7

I have a small javascript control that allows users to select a date and time.

Part of the control uses another date selector. This date selector works as expected and puts the selected value in a field. The users then select the hour, the minutes (in 15 min increments) and am/pm from drop downs.

The data comes to look like this:

```
followUpDate = 10/24/2012
hour = 06
minute = 30
ampm = AM
```

However, IE7 will not return the values of the dropdown.

I'm using

```
var hour = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
```

and the hour (and subsequent variables) are still undefined in IE7. However, the values are correct in IE8+ and the other major browsers.

Comment: Why not just create a Date instance for the correct day, and then explicitly set the hours/minutes/seconds with the setter APIs (`setHours()`, `setMinutes()`, `setSeconds()`)?

Comment: @Pointy Trying your suggestion actually led me to find the error. I've answered my own question. Thanks for the direction.

Comment: @justnS The answer would make this question a textbook example for "too localised"

Comment: @millimoose well changing the title so that it's about IE7 not returning the default option value could redeem it :-)

Comment: @millimoose I've changed the question to reflect the underlying problem I encountered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My problem was I was using:

```
var hour = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
```

instead of:

```
 var hour = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
```

So IE7 wouldn't get the value of the dropdowns kept the values at undefined. However, IE8+ and the other browsers accepted .value and worked as expected.